# PowerMockito spy not stopping abstract method from being called

Tags: java, powermock

I have the following classes, I'm trying to stop getString() from actually being called but it seems to get called, and throw an exception, every time. Am I using PowerMockito and spy correctly?

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected String getString(String str){
        //databse stuff causing exception
    }
}

public class ImplClass extends AbstractClass{
    //getInstance() and private contructor
    public String method(){
        String str = getString("str");
    }
}

public class ImplClassTest{
    public void testMethod(){
        ImplClass impl = ImplClass.getInstance();
        ImplClass spy = PowerMockito.spy(impl);
        PowerMockito.doReturn("spy string").when(spy).method();
        impl.method(); //this line is still getting exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
impl.method(); //this line is still getting exception
```

you should call

```
spy.method();
```

Comment: My hero. So when you create a spy, should you pretty much only use the spy object? In other words, once you create a spy, the original "real" object should not be used? I'm new to testing and mocking :/

Comment: Exactly. You should now use only your spy object. Good luck in testing :)